ABP does not recognize installed .net
I tried to follow in a workshop at the WeAreDevelopers conference, but using a Linux based machine, I had the problem that even though installing the abp framework worked, the abp command refused to work due to a supposedly missing dotnet installation.
What am I missing?
Here's the terminal output:
user@machine:~/Development/WAD/Demos$ dotnet tool install -g Volo.Abp.Cli
Tool 'volo.abp.cli' was reinstalled with the stable version (version '8.2.0').
user@machine:~/Development/WAD/Demos$ abp new Acme.BookStore -t app
You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /home/user/.dotnet/tools/abp
Architecture: x64
App host version: 8.0.7
.NET location: Not found

Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=linux-x64&os=ubuntu.22.04&apphost_version=8.0.7
user@machine:~/Development/WAD/Demos$ dotnet --list-sdks
8.0.303 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
user@machine:~/Development/WAD/Demos$ dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.303
 Commit:            29ab8e3268
 Workload version:  8.0.300-manifests.7ccdde63
 MSBuild version:   17.10.4+10fbfbf2e

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  22.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/

.NET workloads installed:
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
  Version:      8.0.7
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       2aade6beb0

.NET SDKs installed:
  8.0.303 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.7 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.7 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
user@machine:~/Development/WAD/Demos$

Many thanks in advance for the support!

does this error occur when you use another dotnet tool?

If you have sudo permissions then can you please check by using sudo command ?

@RohitJadhav :
user@machine:~$ sudo abp new Acme.BookStore -t app
[sudo] password for user:
sudo: abp: command not found

@Salih good hint. Yes, that also happens with other tools (just tried ReSharper CLI tools)
